# Blank screen after trying to fix

Tags: 16.04, login

I downloaded a couple of rather large files, and perhaps did a software update.  When I went to login the next day I was in the login loop. This was in version **14.10**, so I thought upgrading to **16.04** might solve it.  It did not.

I tried several of the Ask Ubuntu suggestions, however when I uninstalled `lightdm` and installed `gdm` (as suggested), I got a black screen flashing different shades of black.  I can no longer get the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to work for the console.

Any suggestions?  I have used Ubuntu for several years but I am not a developer.

Comment: If you did indeed do an update it's possible an updated kernel was involved. in which case you should be able to choose a previous kernel from the grub menu.

Comment: Try booting a different (previous) kernel on the Grub menu of Ubuntu

Comment: Tried different kernel no luck.

Comment: What is the output of `cat ~/.xsession-errors`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue a few days ago. Login in with safe mode go to terminal and update navida with

> sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

Comment: Did the above command line and no change

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is between `purge` and `remove --purge`, but I had my parents run `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*` and that took care of the problem for them. You should be able to run `dpkg --list | grep nvidia` to see all of the packages that will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar after updating system on Monday (7th) to:

```
uname -a
Linux ***** 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have an AMD graphics card and the radeon drivers were updated along with the kernel. Falling back to a previous kernel did not help, still stuck in login loop. The only thing that enabled me to log on was to unplug the monitor from the AMD card and use the onboard (intel) VGA port instead. This is sufficient for me to carry on working, but obviously not a long term solution and won't work for laptop users.

Answer (score 0):

After several suggestions and attempts, I finally got the command prompt I needed by changing:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"

From there I copied all the important items off the harddrive.

Finally to fix the problem, I put the graphics card that came with the computer (8 years ago) and reboot the system and now can get to a terminal to continue.